# How to load a bean only if the property value is other than a fixed value

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am facing a situation in which a bean should be created by the application context only if the property contains any other value than a specific value.
i.e... one property `file.path= /specific/path`, If the value is other than this then bean should be loaded.

I can see that there is `@ConditionalOnProperty (name="file.path", havingValue="....")` out of the box but in my case, I am looking a property like `havingValueOtherThan="..."` or similar kind of property or annotation if it is there out of the box in the spring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many possible options, besides profiles that were stated in comments, here are 2 options:

**Option 1**

Use `@ConditionalOnExpression` with any SPeL expression you wish

**Option 2**

You can always create your own conditional annotation with any logic:

Create an annotation that will depict your own business case with a `@Conditional` on it. 
Then Implement the conditional logic of your choice. [Here](https://blog.andresteingress.com/2017/09/21/spring-boot-conditional-annotations.html) is an example of achieving this.

BTW, the profiles that mentioned in comments are using Conditionals engine under the hood (The `@Profile` annotation has a `@Conditional({ProfileCondition.class})` in its definition since Spring 4.x)

Comment: Hi @Mark Bramnik, I did resolve the issue by using the option 1 but i am not sure what is the actual performance impact by using the `@ConditinalOnExpression` or option 2 ?. And need one more suggestion can't we add an api like `havingValueOtherThan()` in  `@ConditionalOnProperty` ?

Comment: Dont worry about the performance impact. Spring evaluates this expression once per bean with such a property, which is on startup of the application. So even if you have hundreds of beans like this it will take a millisecond or so for all of them overall. If you really need a custom condition - the create a conditional with the logic of your choice...